# NodeJS vs PHP+Apache performance test has weird results

Tags: php, node.js, performance, apache

I am trying to choose the best technology for my API so I've created the simplest script ever:

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$r = [];

for($i=0;$i<=1000000;$i++) {
    $r[] = $i;
}

echo json_encode($r);
```

**Node:**

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var i, ret = [];

    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});

    for(i=0;i<=1000000;i++) {
        ret.push(i);
    }

    response.end(JSON.stringify(ret));
}).listen(8080);
```

---

Apache has a pretty default configuration without and is clean of fancy optiomizations

The response time is about 1.5s-2.3s for both PHP+Apache and NodeJS which is really weird..So do I do something wrong with node or its just that this specific functionality has no advantage over PHP+Apache?

---

The API should ultimatley recieve calls, insert it to a database on one side and on the other side it should fetch those results. The api should recieve about ~1million calls per day and it should be scalable so i'm trying to figure out what is the best approach here and the performance test results confused me a bit.

Comment: Try your node.js and PHP code *without* `json_encode($r)` and `response.end(JSON.stringify(ret));` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Why would you expect even a difference on such a basic operation ?

Comment: The real power of node.js it's not a basic operations but event loop, try do apache benchmark on this serwers, and you get a answear ;)

Comment: Yeah I can see the difference :) When I iterate 10M PHP can't handle it and Node handles it very well.

Stupid me ^_^

Comment: Simple test scripts for benchmarking is useless. Just choose which one is easier for you and use it.

Comment: Alternatively, don't remove the json encoding (that's simulating transmitting large files) instead test it using apachebench instead of just one request. You'll find that even though node and php both process a single request with roughly the same amount of time node tend to be able to process more of such requests per second.

Comment: Can you paste a ab results for test ? :>

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the performance benchmark results depends on the type of programs/applications you're running for benchmarking.

There are usually two types of performance measure. One is server side performance( it is measured by calculating the CPU and memory usage of the corresponding technology in the  server (Linux  Box)) and another is client side performance (It is measured by the response time using tools like Apache Bench).

**Server Side CPU and Memory Usage Benchmarks :** Debian.org benchmarks different programming languages/framework in Linux Box (Ubuntu). It uses a set of different types of program to measure the performance. It can be an ideal source of information. However, it only measure the server side CPU and memory usage. You can find the benchmarking result between Node and other languages (e.g. PHP) in the following link:

https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/which-programs-are-fastest.html
https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/compare.php?lang=node&lang2=php

According to their result, Node performs significantly better compared to PHP in terms of CPU usage.

**Client Side Response Time Benchmarks:**  Hostingadvice has compared  Node vs PHP performance in the client side. They measured the performance in terms of client side response time. You can find the result in the following link:
http://www.hostingadvice.com/blog/comparing-node-js-vs-php-performance/

According to their result, Node performs significantly better than PHP in terms of client side response time.